# Writing to a file in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, filewriter

I am writing a Scala code that requires me to write to a file in HDFS.
When I use `Filewriter.write` on local, it works. The same thing does not work on HDFS. 
Upon checking, I found that there are the following options to write in Apache Spark- 
`RDD.saveAsTextFile` and `DataFrame.write.format`.

My question is: what if I just want to write an int or string to a file in Apache Spark?

Follow up:
I need to write to an output file a header, DataFrame contents and then append some string.
Does `sc.parallelize(Seq(<String>))` help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

create `RDD` with your data (int/string) using `Seq`: see [parallelized-collections](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections) for details:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(5))  //for writing int (5)
sc.parallelize(Seq("Test String")) // for writing string
```

---

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Writing Int to File").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
val intRdd= sc.parallelize(Seq(5))   
intRdd.saveAsTextFile("out\\int\\test")
```

---

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Writing string to File").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)   
val stringRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("Test String"))
stringRdd.saveAsTextFile("out\\string\\test")
```

Comment: Thanks. That did work. I am editing my question with a follow-up if you can help.

Comment: Once you accept an answer, it's better to post new question.

Answer (score 6):

**Follow up Example:** (Tested as below)

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Total Countries having Icon").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val headerRDD= sc.parallelize(Seq("HEADER"))

//Replace BODY part with your DF
val bodyRDD= sc.parallelize(Seq("BODY"))

val footerRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq("FOOTER"))

//combine all rdds to final    
val finalRDD = headerRDD ++ bodyRDD ++ footerRDD 

//finalRDD.foreach(line => println(line))

//output to one file
finalRDD.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile("test")
```

---

output:

```
HEADER
BODY
FOOTER
```

[more examples here. . .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914760/add-a-new-line-to-a-text-file-in-spark)