# Writing ListBuffer[List[Any]] values into CSV using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have now re-framed my question.

I'm learning scala and spark. I'm aware of directly creating RDD from csv file instead of creating DF and converting it to RDD. But, I'm trying the below combination.

Creating scala ListBuffer, Spark Dataframe and converting it to RDD:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> var src_policy_final = new ListBuffer[List[Any]]
src_policy_final: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[List[Any]] = ListBuffer()

scala> var src_policy_final = new ListBuffer[List[Any]]
src_policy_final: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[List[Any]] = ListBuffer()

scala> var src_policy_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("sparktest/policy_details.csv")
src_policy_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [policy_id: int, otherdetails: string]

scala> var src_rdd = src_policy_df.rdd.map(_.toSeq.toList)
src_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Any]] = MapPartitionsRDD[40] at map at <console>:26

scala> var src_pol_list = src_rdd.collect.toList
src_pol_list: List[List[Any]] = List(List(10110000, This is the first policy), List(10456200, This is the second policy), List(10345300, This is the third policy))
```

Using scala for loop I'm iterating Spark RDD records to replace column value(policy_id with surrogateId) as shown below -

```
scala> for(pol_details <- src_pol_list){
     | src_policy_final += pol_details.toList.map(e => if(e==10110000) 1345678 else e)
     | }
```

I'm changing the specific column values of the record using `.map(e => if(e==orig_pol_id) ref_surr_id else e)` and adding the records to `ListBuffer[List[Any]]`. Once I complete iterating throw all the records in RDD I would write the `ListBuffer[Lis[Any]]` values as a csv file into HDFS file system using function `SaveAsTextFile("/sparktest/policy_details")`

When I do println of src_policy_final, the output is:

```
    scala> println(src_policy_final)
ListBuffer(List(1345678, This is the first policy), List(10456200, This is the second policy), List(10345300, This is the third policy))
```

Now, I'm writing the modified data back to HDFS file system by converting ListBuffer[ListAny]] it into an RDD:

```
scala> var src_write = sc.parallelize(src_policy_final.toList)
src_write: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[Any]] = ParallelCollectionRDD[43] at parallelize at <console>:53
```

Writing to HDFS file system:

```
scala> src_write.saveAsTextFile("sparktest/pol_det")
```

The output data looks like:

```
List(1345678, This is the first policy)
List(10456200, This is the second policy)
List(10345300, This is the third policy)
```

The output that would like to get is:

```
1345678, This is the first policy
10456200, This is the second policy
10345300, This is the third policy
```

I'm not sure how to load the output as per my requirement.

Hope, I have given better explaining about what I'm trying to achieve.Could you please help?

Comment: Is my question having any issue? or Am I not clear in explaining?

Comment: Hi @VijayB, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: BTW, you may give a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173039/writing-to-a-file-in-apache-spark

Comment: Not clear why this is tagged with Spark. If you just want to write HDFS CSV data, you can use an OutputStream and you write directly to HDFS

Comment: Hi @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I have re-framed my question

Comment: Hi  @cricket_007, I'm new to Big data technologies and upgrading myself. Trying different method of loading files into HDFS and later will be exploring to write the file into Amazon S3 using Spark and Scala.

Comment: There would only be a one line difference in using HDFS or S3 with Spark, but still, it's not required at all to just get a file into either place

Comment: Anyway, you need to use `RDD[Row]`, not a List of Scala buffers... You're seeing it print the `toString` representation of the objects because it doesn't know what to do with them. Ideally, you should be using a Dataset object, though, not RDD

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, I'm still in learning phase.Sure, I will try this option and let you know if I get stuck.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really do not understand what is all you want to do...
But, since you said that you are learning I will try to explain everything step by step - hope it helps you.

First, as an advice from a colleague that switched from Java to Scala a couple of years ago. Avoid all mutations as possible, force yourself to think and program in *functional* way - thus, use `val` instead of `var` and **immutable** collections instead of **mutable** ones.

Second, avoid as possible using things of type `Any`, for example here...

```
var src_rdd = src_policy_df.rdd.map(_.toSeq.toList)
```

... you may fetch the values you want from each `Row` in a more typed way, for example:

```
val src_rdd = src_policy_df.rdd.map { row =>
   (
      row.getAs[Int](fieldName = "policy_id"),
      row.getAs[String](fieldName = "otherdetails")
   )
}
// src_rdd: RDD[(Int, String)]
```

Or even better, use a `Dataset` *(a **Typed** DataFrame)*.

```
import spark.implicits._ // spark is an instance of SparkSession
final case class Policy(policy_id: Int, otherdetails: String)
val src_dataset = src_policy_df.as[Policy] // implicit Encoder needed here, provided by the spark implicits.
```

In Spark, you **should never** `collect` your data - except as the last step of your computation pipeline *(and in most cases this is only done in a debug phase, because in general you save it to a external data store, like HDFS or mongo)*, or if you are sure you have a small `RDD` which you want to make accessible to other transformations as a lookup table or something similar *(for example, this is very common on reduced pair RDDs, thus there exist the `reduceByKeyLocally` method which will return a **Map**)*.
Why? - Because `collect` brings all the data that was distributed on the **Executors** to the **Driver** that means, you are not longer using the framework to parallelize your computations.
What you should do is build your computation using the **Transformations** provided by Spark, for example `map`.

```
val orig_pol_id = 10110000
val ref_surr_id = 1345678

// Using RDDs.
val src_policy_final_rdd = src_rdd.map {
  case (id, otherdetails) if (id == orig_pol_id) => (ref_surr_id, otherdetails)
  case policy => policy // default case, nothing change.
}

// Using Datasets.
val src_policy_final_dataset = src_dataset.map {
  case policy if (policy.id == orig_pol_id) => policy.copy(id = ref_surr_id) // the copy method returns a new policy with the provided fields changed.
  case policy => policy // default case, nothing change.
}
```

Finally when writing the `RDD` to **HDFS**, it uses the default `toString` on each element to print each line. So, you may need to format it before saving.

```
val write_rdd = src_policy_final_rdd.map {
   case (id, otherdetails) => s"$id,$otherdetails"
}
// wirte_rdd: RDD[String]
src_write.saveAsTextFile("sparktest/pol_det")
```

Or, if you are using a `Dataset`, you can use the **DataframeWriter** api, to handle all that for you. *(Recommended)*

```
src_policy_final_dataset
  .write
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("sep", ",") // ',' is the default separator, but I prefer to be specific.
  .csv("sparktest/pol_det")
```

This should address all your question.

PS: Two final notes.
Frist, in general this question is *"too board"* for being asked/answered in **SO** - thus try to limit your scope and be more clear the next time ;).
And, you may try reading first about Spark and doing quick tutorials to get yourself more comfortable with the framework - btw, [this](https://github.com/pslcorp/spark-scala-workshop) is short spark *workshop* i made for the office a few days ago, it was intended for not-Scala developers, hope it helps you too :)

Comment: Hi @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, First of all, A very big Thank you for the detailed explanation :) . Sure, I will go through Spark tutorial to understand it better before implementing it.

Comment: @VijayB, you are welcome if you have any problems with the code in this answer don't doubt to ask for clarification. Btw, you may give a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I don't have privilege yet to vote. This question has made me down instead of increasing my reputation :(

Comment: @VijayB no problem.